# Geopy Error with Reverse Geocoding

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I am using [Geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/). I get following error for the code.

I have using the same code as on https://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/ReverseGeocoding

from geopy import geocoders

```
g = geocoders.GeoNames()
(place, point) = g.geocode("Palo Alto, CA 94306")
print place
>> "Palo Alto, US 94306"
print point
>> (37.418008999999998, -122.127375)

(new_place,new_point) = g.reverse(point)
print new_place
>> 3998 Ventura Ct, Palo Alto, US 94306 
print new_point
>> (37.417850000000001, -122.12793000000001)
```

Works fine till print point. Error occurs with `g.reverse(point)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 9, in reverse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm, on OSX with version 0.95.1 of geopy in a virtualenv I get a `NotImplementedError` on `g.reverse(point)` as well. I'm thinking this _maybe_ hasn't made it from dev to trunk yet? Might want to get with the geopy maintainer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the development branch, as it mentioned in the link you provided?

> The reverse geocoding feature is ***currently in an experimental but
> stable development branch***, which you can checkout here:
>
> svn checkout http://geopy.googlecode.com/svn/branches/reverse-geocode
> geopy
>
> cd geopy/ sudo
>
> python setup.py install
>
> *You may have to delete your old geopy installation.*

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding available on geopy 0.97. You can download and install new version of geopy from https://github.com/geopy/geopy or clone the git repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/geopy/geopy.git
cd geopy
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you want to download and install for windows, you can get a latest version from https://github.com/geopy/geopy/archive/release-0.97.zip

Unzip and

```
cd geopy-release-0.97
python setup.py install
```

To geolocate a query to an address and coordinates:

```py
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
>>> address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>>> print(address, latitude, longitude)
175 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10010, USA 40.7410262 -73.9897806
```

To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates:

```py
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
>>> address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.reverse("40.752067, -73.977578")
>>> print(address, latitude, longitude)
77 East 42nd Street, New York, NY 10017, USA 40.7520802 -73.9775683
```

--
Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991832/2509803