# Max retries exceeded with URL in Nominatim with GeoPy

Tags: python, nominatim, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I'm trying to get a country name by lat lon (reverse encoding) using Python. I got to Nominatim with GeoPy which worked great two times but now I keep getting Max retries exceeded error.

My code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def get_countries(lat,lon):
    coordinates = f'{lat} {lon}'
    locator = Nominatim(user_agent='myencoder', timeout=10)
    location = locator.reverse(coordinates,language='en')
    country = location.raw['address']['country_code'].upper()
    return [country,lat,lon]

get_countries(32.782023,35.478867)
```

In practice I would like to use this function for about 100-200 locations, but I get the error also for this one location. It worked the first time I run the code, but then I'm keep getting:

```
GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=32.782023&lon=35.478867&format=json&accept-language=en&addressdetails=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F7AA229978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

I've tried changing the `user_agent` by writing my email or another name as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293615/user-agent-argument-in-nominatim-in-geopy), I also read the answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/geopy-error-with-reverse-geocoding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914648/geopy-catch-timeout-error), also other solutions. All resulted in this error.

What else can I do? Are there other reliable options using Python to get a country name (preferably with to letters e.g., ES, IT, US, etc.) by lat lon?

Comment: Have you tried RateLimiter (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331236)? See also: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#usage-with-pandas

Comment: Hi, I did not try it yet, I found some kind of work-around using a SHP file of all the countries around the globe, but I'll give it a try once I'll have time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If GeoPy usage is not mandatory, one can try to achieve the desired output with the [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package and the [The Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/).

There will be a request sent like a [Reverse geocoding](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/) based on the following URL:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=<value>&lon=<value>&<params>
```

However, the above link needs several adjustments:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=<value>&lon=<value>&format=json&accept-language=en&zoom=3
```

*where:*

- `format=json` : Output format
- `accept-language=en` : Language of results
- `zoom=3` : Result limitation for country

```py
import requests

def get_country(lat, lon):
    url = f'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&format=json&accept-language=en&zoom=3'
    try:
        result = requests.get(url=url)
        result_json = result.json()
        return result_json['display_name']
    except:
        return None

print(get_country(32.782023,35.478867)) # results in Israel
```

The output in Browser shall look like this :

[image: result]

To get only two letters, one can try the following code:

```py
import requests

def get_country(lat, lon):
    url = f'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&format=json&namedetails=1&accept-language=en&zoom=3'
    try:
        result = requests.get(url=url)
        result_json = result.json()
        return result_json['address']['country_code'].upper()
    except:
        return None

print(get_country(32.782023,35.478867)) # results in IL
```